# onchange javascript to dynamically change links

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, edit, onchange

I want to edit links when the user changes the value of a `<input type="text">`, but I can't get it to work. My HTML:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateGiveLink() {
        document.getElementById("givelink").innerHTML = "http://kroltan.eliti.com.br/diamonds/?give="+document.getElementsById("givetext").value;
        document.getElementById("givelink").href = "http://kroltan.eliti.com.br/diamonds/?give="+document.getElementsById("givetext").value;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Minecraft username" name="give" id="givetext" onchange="updateGiveLink()" /> 
    <a id="givelink" href="http://kroltan.eliti.com.br/diamonds/?give=Player">http://kroltan.eliti.com.br/diamonds/?give=Player</a>
```

This is supposed to change the URL and display text of `givelink` so the `?give=` part of the url has the value of the text field `givetext`. But it is not working as expected. Instead, it does nothing. I also tried using `onkeyup` and `oninput` (saw these in another related question), with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `document.getElementById("givetext").value` you had `getElementsBy` with an `s`

Working code using `onkeyup` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73qZq/)

Comment: Blame Eclipse, and its auto completion!

Answer (score 1):

May be there is some syntax error as you have used document.getElementsById but it should be document.getElementById